# Область видимости у декоратора

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
def logger(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        a = 6
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
@logger
def nothing():
    print(a)
```

Выходит ошибка, что переменная a неопределенна, не совсем понимаю по какому принципу он ищет ее в области видимости. Можете объяснить?

Comment: Мне казалось, что будет вызов функции f в inner и он оттуда же будет спускаться по LEGB вниз по областям видимости.

Comment: `nothing` это обычная функция, `a` локальная переменная в совсем другой функции

Comment: Так если написать a = 6 в logger, то внезапно код начнет выполняться, я не понимаю, почему его верхняя область видимости это logger.

Comment: Хотя, я кажется, уже начинаю понимать, видимо это связано с тем, что декоратор возращает inner и для него уже нет этой внутренней функции.

Comment: [Не начнёт выполняться](https://repl.it/repls/AridUntimelyFirm), декоратор только говорит `nothing = logger(nothing)`

Comment: А, окей... Видимо у меня переменная была где-то раньше определена, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у "декоратора" такая же область видимости что и у любого другого метода. в данном случае переменная `a` объявлена в методе `inner` и видна только в нем.

если вынести объявление переменной `a` из `inner` в `logger`, то `a` будет видна и в `logger` и в `inner`. поэтому слово декоратор я взял в ковычки, потому что декоратор это паттерн, а вопрос об области видимости вложенных методов. однако в методе `nothing` переменная `a` не будет доступна никогда, потому что он выполняется в своей области видимости.

```
def logger(f):
    a = ""
    print("logger:", locals())

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal a
        b = ""
        print("logger.inner:", locals())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@logger
def nothing():
    c = ""
    print("nothing:", locals())

nothing()
```

```
logger: {'a': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7f981115f4d0>}
logger.inner: {'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'b': '', 'a': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7f981115f4d0>}
nothing: {'c': ''}
```

для вложенной функции `inner` переменные объявленные в функции `logger` доступны в режиме read-only. ключевое слово `nonlocal` в данном случае позволяет изменять переменную объявленнию на скоуп выше.

интересно, что без `nonlocal` переменная `a` не видна в `locals()` если она не упоминается в коде `inner`.

```
def logger(f):
    a = ""
    print("logger:", locals())

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        b = ""
        print("logger.inner:", locals())
        print(a)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@logger
def nothing():
    c = ""
    print("nothing:", locals())

nothing()
```

```
logger: {'a': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7faa790214d0>}
logger.inner: {'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'b': '', 'a': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7faa790214d0>}

nothing: {'c': ''}
```

```
def logger(f):
    a = ""
    print("logger:", locals())

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        b = ""
        print("logger.inner:", locals())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@logger
def nothing():
    c = ""
    print("nothing:", locals())

nothing()
```

```
logger: {'a': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7f20117c44d0>}
logger.inner: {'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'b': '', 'f': <function nothing at 0x7f20117c44d0>}
nothing: {'c': ''}
```

а вот метод `nothing` никакого отношения к `logger` и `inner` не имеет.